# How to prevent the user data from being inserted in DB every time the page reloads?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have this function where I check if user can join a channel and then I insert this data to DB. The problem is it gets inserted every time I reload the page. How to prevent this from happening?

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
     $ip = Request::ip();
     $time = now();
  if (auth()->check()) { 
    UserInfo::storeUser();
      return [
        'id' => $user->id,
        'ip' => $ip,
        'name' => $user->name,
        'joined' => $time
    ];
  }
});
```

Comment: create a session or active state in your db which will check if the user data is inserted. If the data is there then do not insert the same data

Comment: @Regolith Could you give me an example?

Comment: create a is_active column in database, when first you insert the data insert 1. and then check every time you reload the page for that is_active an if it is 1 then do not insert. Also when you logout or end the session change the active state to 0. which will let you create new record if the function is used again in another time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need any mode of determining that you have already stored the information of this user.
**DB**, **session**, or even the **auth()->user()** object(*this one depends on the use case*) can store this data.

Take an example of session:

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    $ip = Request::ip();
    $time = now();
    if (auth()->check() && !session()->has('user_id')){ 
        UserInfo::storeUser();
        session()->put('user_id',$user->id);
        return [
           'id' => $user->id,
           'ip' => $ip,
           'name' => $user->name,
           'joined' => $time
       ];
    }
});
```

and on logout:

```
session()->forget('user_id')
```

Bear in mind, this is a basic example without much context.